# Rest API V1 No longer Active

Tags: ios, objective-c, twitter

I'm using a twitter API to fetch latest tweets from some person.
It was working well until 16 June 2013.

But now it gives me error - "410 error - rest api v1 not active" while fetching tweets.

Can anyone please help me out to migrate api version 1.1 over 1.0? 
or 
any other solution

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I never worked with twitter http api directly. If your twitter codebase is small then you can refactor your code by using a library or implementing some kind of abstraction to make migration to later minor API changes less painful.

As I can see from [this article](https://dev.twitter.com/blog/changes-coming-to-twitter-api) migration seems pretty straightforward. You should always authenticate your requests for all API calls.

Answer (score 0):

API v1 was retired recently, as outlined [here](https://dev.twitter.com/blog/api-v1-retirement-date-extended-to-june-11). To get up and running again, look at the changes from 1.0 to 1.1 [here](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/overview#Deprecation_of_v1.0_of_the_API) or [here](https://dev.twitter.com/blog/api-v1-retirement-final-dates).